# Consuming SOAP WebService with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap

I'm trying to consume a SOAP (.net) WebService with JavaScript but the responseText and the responseXML are null. I tried running in another browser(chrome, firefox, IE) but that didn't solve it.

```
function MButton1Click(event) {
    sendDataAsXML_SOAP();
}


function sendDataAsXML_SOAP() {
    var req_params = "",
        url = "",
        number = 0,
        type = "";
    /* Configure Parameters */
    url = "http://wp.art.br/FriendNet/Principal.asmx";
    var user = document.getElementById("MTextArea1").value;
    var ajaxRequest;
    req_params = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
    req_params = req_params + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-       instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"   xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
    req_params = req_params + "  <soap:Body>";
    req_params = req_params + "    <TesteDeTexto xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">";
    req_params = req_params + "      <pTexto>" + user + "</pTexto>";
    req_params = req_params + "    </TesteDeTexto>";
    req_params = req_params + "  </soap:Body>";
    req_params = req_params + "</soap:Envelope>";
    /* Send XML/SOAP Request To Web Service Using Browser's Javascript DOM */
    var xmlHTTP;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHTTP = new window.XMLHttpRequest; //For browsers other than ie
    } else {
        try {
            xmlHTTP = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); //for ie
        } catch (ex) {}
    }
    xmlHTTP.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/TesteDeTexto");
    xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = receiveXML_SOAPData;
    xmlHTTP.send(req_params);
}

function receiveXML_SOAPData() {
    if (ajax_request.readyState == 4) {
        if (ajax_request.status == 200 || ajax_request.status == 0) {
            /* Parse The Response Data */
            alert(ajax_request.responseText);
            alert(ajax_request.responseXML);
            alert("sucesso");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to use a `ajax_request` in your `receiveXML_SOAPData` function which is `undefined`. You should have gotten an exception from that, check your error console.

The `ajaxrequest` variable in the `sendDataAsXML_SOAP` function is a) not used and b) local to that function - it would not work.

Use the `this` keyword in the `receiveXML_SOAPData` function to reference the XHR object instead.

Comment: but the ajax_request in receiveXML_SOAPData works. If I do:

               function receiveXML_SOAPData() {
                alert(ajax_request.readyState)
               if (ajax_request.readyState == 4) {
        if (ajax_request.status == 200 || ajax_request.status == 0) {
            /* Parse The Response Data */
            alert(ajax_request.responseText);
              alert(ajax_request.responseXML);
            alert("sucesso");
        }
    }

then alert 4

Comment: Unlikely. Do you really have posted the full code in your question? Anyway: If the reponses are `null`, do you try to do a cross-domain request?

Comment: AAh, now I understood you and instanced the variable ajax_request as global. When I print ajax_request, priny "HTTPRequest Object", when I print responseText, print "  " and when I print responseXML, print "null"

Comment: why is the ajax_request.responseXML  = null and the ajax_request.responseText = " "?

Comment: The responseXML is `null` because the responseText is no valid XML string. Why the responseText is only a space, I don't know - can you confirm the server sent something else?

Comment: Yes, the server sent a xml. I can consume in Objective-C but doesn't work in javascript

Comment: I don't think the headers are the very same. Use the network panel of the browser's developer tools to monitor the exact request.

Comment: I have pressed ctrl + shift + I in Google Chrome and saw these error:

Comment: Which errors? And what does the network panel show for your request?